# How does this work? Data catching without displaying client

Tags: c#, data

Alright so this is about a game, but more generally this can probably be done for all games, I just want to figure out how the application accomplishes it.

So it's for a game called League of Legends, huge game, has an executable file and a massive LoLClient where you can view all data specific to your account, you can queue for games etc.

Now what this app does (that I've came across) is it logs into the league client, grabs all info related to the character and logs out) but it does this without even displaying the client on the users screen, how is this possible? bare in mind it isnt using a server.

A broad question perhaps, but im sure there's a straight forward question (app developed in C#)

Comment: What APP are you talking about? Also, I think what you are looking for is the LoL API (Riot provides it). You can get information about players, and the game in general for your own developed APP/Program if you use this API.

Comment: Forgot to link it. Here you have it: https://developer.riotgames.com/

Comment: Riot doesn't have anything in the API that allows devs to take credentials, log in with those credentials then stick the user in queue for a game. This seems to be done without the riot api